# Regex: Only want space character before and after match

Tags: python, regex, nltk, tokenize

I am using Regex tokenizer for a text passage, and I would like to extract all words that only have white space before and after that. Here is my code:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('[0-9a-z][^\s\']*[a-z]')
```

For instance, the sentence "we don't have 500 dollars" will end up becoming "we don have dollars". I would like to have "don" eliminated since it does not end with a whitespace. How do I do so?

Comment: Use a lookahead assertion: `r'[0-9a-z]*?= '` .  The result should be "we t have 500".  "dollars" won't match because it's not followed by whitespace.

Comment: @TimRoberts That looks like a typo. You probably meant `r'[0-9a-z]*?(?=\s)'`

Comment: Presumably you are asking about NLTK? I added the [tag:nltk] tag, but please review.

Comment: Agree, should have indicated more about the context. Agree poster probably meant nltk

Comment: I apologize. The match can end without a whitespace such as a full stop. However, I don't want the match to end with an apostrophe " ' ". Also I need the match to begin with a white space too. So this means I definitely want to end up with "we have dollars". I wonder if the following code works:

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('(?<!\S)[0-9a-z][^\s\']*[a-z](?<!^\')')

Is there anything wrong? How can I edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead and lookbehind to achieve this

**Code:**

import re

```
pattern = r"(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:(?=\s)|(?=$))"
print(re.findall(pattern, "we don't have 500 dollars"))
print(re.findall(pattern, "Your money's no good here, Mr. Torrance"))
```

Output:

```
['we', 'have', '500', 'dollars']
['Your', 'no', 'good', 'Torrance']
```

You can play around with this here
https://regex101.com/r/IeLC88/3

Comment: When I executed the code, it returned an error message: error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern.

Comment: Probably better to replace `(?<=\s|^)` simply with `\b`. The third-party `regex` library will allow you to use variable-width lookbehinds but I don't know how easy that will be to graft onto NLTK. For English this simple fix is probably sufficient, though there are probably languages where you would really like to have a more flexible definition of the starting word boundary.

Comment: @tripleee you are variable-width won't work here, but adding \b would also detect `'t` in the mix. I instead created non capturing groups and the added alternatives to avoid fixed with issue

Comment: @TanPengshiAlvin updated the answer to include non capturing group with alternatives to get around the fixed-width issue